# jQuery Touch Punch and css3 translate?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery UI Touch Punch. I can drag everything just fine, but when I use css3's "translsateY", it works on the computer, but doesnt on iPad. The element just jumps up on dragstart and then I can drag it around. Did someone else have this problem?

I have tried to use set translateY on my element on dragstart, but it didn't change anything. When I leave translate away, the element is in the wrong position, but at least drag works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now wrote my own "translate" function. I took half the height of the object in jQuery via `.outerHeight()` and added this to the `top:50%`. This way you don't need to use `translateY` and it won't conflict with `.draggable`.